# Что не так с моим запросом? FROM shop WHERE reting = 7 AND reting = 8;

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица `shop` в ней есть поля: `name`, `shop_name`, `price`, `reting`, где

- `name` = имя товара.
- `shop_name` = имя магазина.
- `price` = цена
- `reting` = рейтинг товаров.

---

```
Содержания таблицы 
____________________________________
name  | shop_name | price | reting |
Apple | Dicsi     |  50   |    7   |
milk  | Narodnyi  |  25   |    8   |
lamp  | Pupsi     |  100  |    7   |
map   | Luk       |  1000 |    8   |
-----------------------------------+
```

Я хочу вывести на экран все записи у которых рейтинг равен 7 и 8,
выполняя этот запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shop 
WHERE reting = 7 AND reting = 8;
```

я получаю абсолютно нечего.
А вот так все правильно :

```
SELECT * 
FROM shop 
WHERE reting = 7 OR reting = 8;
```

вывод :

```
----------------------+
name     |   reting   |
----------------------+
Apple    |     7      |
Milk     |     8      |
----------------------+
```

Почему это так, ведь тут сказано https://sql-language.ru/sql-and-or.html
оператор `AND`  выводить все записи если оба условия будет истинным. А тут истинно, `reting` 
в этом случае равно 7 и 8 в таблице видно.

Почему так.

Comment: Все условия проверяются по отдельности для каждой записи. Все условия взятые для одной конкретной записи должны быть истиной. Берем для проверки первую запись "Apple,   7", проверяем условия `reting=7` да, совпало, проверяем второе условие `reting=8` нет, не равно, вот запись и не вывелась в случае если условия объединены `И`. Да в переводе на русский условие с OR лучше смотрится "выбери  такие записи где рейтинг 7 ИЛИ 8"

Answer (score 6):

> Почему это так, ведь тут сказано https://sql-language.ru/sql-and-or.html оператор AND выводить все записи если оба условия будет истинным

Вы пытаетесь вывести продукты, у которых поле `reting` одновременно равно и `7`, и `8`. Но, очевидно, что каждому продукту можно присвоить лишь одно значение, и у одного продукта одновременно рейтинг не может иметь 2 значения. Для того и нужно использовать оператор `OR`.